# order with image template . softlayer api functions

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

standard orders  with the same specifications as  image template orders.
I want to know what the difference.

What are ordering information set template image?

Answer (score 0):

SoftLayer Image Templates provide a method to capture an image of a device in order to quickly replicate its configuration with minimal manipulations in the order process. SoftLayer currently provides two options for creating image templates, each offering unique features based on your operating system and the type of image you wish to create.

you can see more information about images templates here https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/image-templates